# SHORTEST_PATH with EXISTS

Tags: sql-server, graph-databases

I have been following the SQL graph database sample as demonstrated here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/graphs/sql-graph-sample?view=sql-server-ver15.

But as I kept working along I had to add an EXISTS to my WHERE clause which already has a MATCH on SHORTEST_PATH. But this is always throwing an error saying the multi-part identifier "<*columnname*>" could not be bound. I have written a query that shows this on their sample database (GraphDemo):

```
SELECT *
FROM Person,
friendOf FOR PATH,
Person FOR PATH as Person2
WHERE MATCH (SHORTEST_PATH(Person(-(friendOf)->Person2)+))
AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Person p3 WHERE p3.ID = Person.ID)
```

Comment: *'"<columnname>" could not be bound"'* *which* column?

Comment: Whatever column you give in the SELECT inside the EXISTS. In the above query its "The multi-part identifier "p3.ID" could not be bound."